# Change one button(element) in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an table that is constructed from a response from an API call and thus uses ng-repeat to display all elements.

The idea is that there should be a "play button" for the user to click after which a short audio clip is played. When the user clicks the play button, the button should change to a "pause button" and the user can click that to pause the audio.

My problem is that when the button is changing from "play" to "pause" it is changing in all the rows of the table(and not just that row i clicked the play button on).

So this is how it looks like in my HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in results">
...
   <i ng-show="playButton" ng-click="playedPreview(false)" class="material-icons small play" style="cursor:pointer;">play_circle_outline</i>

   <i ng-show="!playButton" ng-click="playedPreview(true)" class="material-icons small pause" style="cursor:pointer;">pause_circle_outline</i> 
...
</tr>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.playedPreview = function(state) {
    $scope.playButton = state;
    console.log($scope.playButton);
}
```

I quickly realized why I'm getting the button is changing in all rows, but I can't figure out how I should do to force it to only change in one row.

I've seen a similar question asked here:
[Having one button in ng-repeat change color when clicked, not all using Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894534/having-one-button-in-ng-repeat-change-color-when-clicked-not-all-using-angularj)

where they're using ng-class to add a class. But the problem for me is that I need the class "play" to play the audio, and the class "pause" to pause the audio. I can't just add a class when it is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to each `r` object instead:

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in results">
   <i ng-show="r.playButton" ng-click="playedPreview(r,false)" class="material-icons small play" style="cursor:pointer;">play_circle_outline</i>    
   <i ng-show="!r.playButton" ng-click="playedPreview(r,true)" class="material-icons small pause" style="cursor:pointer;">pause_circle_outline</i> 
</tr>
```

In controller

```
$scope.playedPreview = function(obj, state) {
    // reset other objects
    $scope.results.forEach(function(item){
           // perhaps use an if(obj !== item) here
           item.playButton = false;
    });
    obj.playButton = state;
    // use to determine what to play perhaps?
    $scope.activeItem = state ? obj : null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array in your controller to memorize the current state of each button that's toggled on click:

```
$scope.btnStates = [];

<tr ng-repeat="r in results">
    <i ng-click="playedPreview(true); btnStates[$index]= !buttonStates[$index];" 
       ng-class="buttonStates[$index] ? 'play' : 'pause'" 
       class="material-icons small">
       {{btnStates[$index]? 'play_circle_outline' : 'pause_circle_outline' }}
    </i>   
</tr>
```